# Why is my htaccess for landing mobile sites isnt working?

Tags: .htaccess, mobile-website

I have to make a landing page for mobile devices, I build (at least I think) a correct `.htaccess` but it is not working...

Can you help me find out what is wrong with it??

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iphone|ipod|android|ipad"
RewriteRule .* http://www.mypage.com/landingmobile [R]
```

EDIT: after a few work and research, I have this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mypage\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iPhone|iPod|Android|iPad)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mypage.com/landingmobile [R]
```

Now i'm trying to redirect direct traffic (when you type the URL in the browser) from mobile phone to the landing mobile site, but when you're on mobile, you search on google and you click the link for my site, you don't have to redirect to anywhere.

Thank you all!!

Comment: if it worked, no mobile device would be able to open any other page on your website...

Comment: That's the point. Don't ask, I have this crazy client

Comment: `%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iPhone|iPod|Android|iPad)`

Comment: Stills not working, GUIDO. Thank you for the approach.

Comment: EDIT because they asked me to add another restriction